# How to increase the speed of the ball when it hits the edge of a paddle and then return back to original speed?

Tags: processing

How to increase the speed of the ball when it hits the edge of a paddle and then return back to original speed? In this pong game, I want my ball to increase its speed when it hits the edge of a paddle and then return back to its normal speed when it hits the middle of the paddle. I commented a few "if statements" because I tried with them and they did not work. The language I am using is "processing"

Comment: please add relevant tag for the language you are using

Comment: Ball position X,Y and Paddle position X,Y will never be the same! As they both have width, in one of the IF statement you took care of paddle's width but haven't considered the ball's width as well. So I think the Coord would be such that Ball X + radius == Paddle X + width or something which considers both their widths to get the exact coords.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIrC5Qcb2G4) is a tutorial about a pong game. I haven't watched it, but I know that at some point (about 75% in) code is added that makes the area where the paddle is hit affect the angle of reflection. Near the edge of the paddle gets a greater angle. I think you can use the same implementation to affect the speed of the ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my ball to increase its speed when it hits the **edge of a paddle** and then return back to its normal speed when it **hits the middle** of the paddle

Add a variable which holds the current speed:

```java
final int MIN_SPEED = 3;
final int MAX_SPEED = 6;
float currentSpeed = (float)MIN_SPEED;
```

Use this variable instead of the `MIN_SPEED`, in the function `bounce`:

```java
void bounce () {
    //bouncing off the top and bottom of the screen  
    if (moveDown) {
        ballPositionY += currentSpeed +(sin(QUARTER_PI));
    } else {
        ballPositionY -= currentSpeed + (sin(QUARTER_PI));
    }

    if (moveRight) {
        ballPositionX += currentSpeed + (sin(HALF_PI + QUARTER_PI));

    } else {
        ballPositionX -= currentSpeed + (sin(-PI));
    }
}
```

To evaluate if the ball hits the middle of the panel, you have to calculate the distance to the center of the paddle. Increase the speed if the paddle is hit by a large distance to the center (al long  `MAX_SPEED` is not reached) and reset the speed to `MIN_SPEED` if the paddle is hit near the center:

```java
void paddleBounce () {

    boolean hitMousePaddleX = ballPositionX >= (mousePaddleX - ballSize/2) && ballPositionX < mousePaddleX;
    boolean hitMousePaddleY = ballPositionY > (mousePaddleY) && ballPositionY < (mousePaddleY + PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    if (hitMousePaddleX && hitMousePaddleY) {

        float distToMidMouse = abs(ballPositionY - (mousePaddleY + PADDLE_HEIGHT/2));
        if ( distToMidMouse < 20.0 ) {
            currentSpeed = MIN_SPEED;
        } else if (currentSpeed < MAX_SPEED) {
            if (currentSpeed < MAX_SPEED) {
                currentSpeed += 0.5;
            }
        } 

        moveRight = false;
    }

    boolean hitKeyPaddleX = ballPositionX <= (keyPaddleX + PADDLE_WIDTH + ballSize/2) && ballPositionX > keyPaddleX;
    boolean hitKeyPaddleY = ballPositionY < (keyPaddleY + PADDLE_HEIGHT) && ballPositionY > keyPaddleY;
    if (hitKeyPaddleX && hitKeyPaddleY) {

        float distToMidKey = abs(ballPositionY - (keyPaddleY + PADDLE_HEIGHT/2));
        if ( distToMidKey < 20.0 ) {
            currentSpeed = MIN_SPEED;
        } else {
            if (currentSpeed < MAX_SPEED) {
                currentSpeed += 0.5;
            }
        }   

        moveRight = true;
    }
}
```

If a new ball, is in the game, the speed hat ot be reset to `MIN_SPEED`:

```java
void scoreCount () {

    if (ballPositionX  < -ballSize/2) {

    mouseScore += 1;
    currentSpeed = MIN_SPEED;
    }

    if (ballPositionX > width + ballSize) {

    keyScore +=  1;
    currentSpeed = MIN_SPEED;
    }
}
```

Ass add on you can tint the ball read by increasing speed:

```java
void drawGame () {

    drawScore ();
    defaultBall ();

    //the ball
    float fSpeed = 1.0 - (currentSpeed - MIN_SPEED) / (MAX_SPEED - MIN_SPEED);
    fill(255, 255*fSpeed, 255*fSpeed);
    strokeWeight (2);
    ellipse (ballPositionX, ballPositionY, ballSize, ballSize);

    fill (255);
    strokeWeight (0.8);
    //the left paddle, which is controlled by the keyboard
    rect (keyPaddleX, keyPaddleY, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);

    //the right paddle, which is controlled by the mouse
    rect (mousePaddleX, mousePaddleY, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code was kinda messy but I managed to find a solution to your problem.
I noticed that the speed of the ball is always "MIN_SPEED" because that's what you affect to your ball position every loop iteration in your bounce method
after looking at the code I noticed that the collision with the paddles was detected in the method "paddleBounce()" , So I went there and affected to MIN_SPEED a higher value of "8" as an example, and to finish I added a lerp version in the draw event to make the value of MIN_SPEED go back to "5" slowly in a non linear way ( so it looks smooth and good )

Here is the final code:

```
 //size of the ball
int ballSize;

//position of the ball
float ballPositionX; 
float ballPositionY; 

//speed of the ball
float ballSpeedX, ballSpeedY;

//size of the paddles
final int PADDLE_WIDTH = (20);
final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = (100);

//coordinates of the LEFT paddle
float keyPaddleY;
float keyPaddleX;

//coordinates of the RIGHT paddle
float mousePaddleX ;
float mousePaddleY;

//score of keyboard
int keyScore = 0;

//score of mouse
int mouseScore = 0;

//movement of the ball
boolean moveDown = true;
boolean moveRight = true;

//gameover
boolean gameOver, moveNewSpeed;

//paddle speed
int paddleSpeed;

 float MIN_SPEED = 3;
final int MAX_SPEED = 6;



void setup () {

  size (500, 500);
  background (#FF7C00);
  frameRate (60);
  ballPositionX = width/2;
  ballPositionY = height/2;

  ballSpeedX = 3;
  ballSpeedY = 3;

  keyPaddleY= 200;
  keyPaddleX = 20;

  mousePaddleX= width - 40;
  mousePaddleY = 200;

  ballSize = 20;

  keyScore = 0;
  mouseScore = 0;

  paddleSpeed = 4;
}

void draw () {

  MIN_SPEED = lerp(MIN_SPEED,3,0.07);


  background (#FF7C00);
  drawGame ();
  bounce ();
  scoreCount ();
  paddleBounce ();
  gameover ();
  canvasBounce ();

  if (keyPressed) {

    if (keyCode == UP) {

      keyPaddleY = keyPaddleY - paddleSpeed;
    }

    /*if ((keyPaddleY == 0) || (keyPaddleY == height )) {

      paddleSpeed = 0;

    }*/ 

    if (keyCode == DOWN) {

      keyPaddleY = keyPaddleY + paddleSpeed;
    }
  }

  /*if ((mousePaddleY == 0) || (mousePaddleY == height )) {

      paddleSpeed = 0;

    }*/

  if (mousePressed) {

    if (mouseButton == LEFT ) {

      mousePaddleY = mousePaddleY - paddleSpeed;
    } 

    if (mouseButton == RIGHT ) {

      mousePaddleY = mousePaddleY + paddleSpeed;
    }
  }
}//VOID BRAC
void drawGame () {

  drawScore ();
  defaultBall ();


  //the ball
  fill ( 255);
  strokeWeight (2);
  ellipse (ballPositionX, ballPositionY, ballSize, ballSize);

  fill (255);
  strokeWeight (0.8);
  //the left paddle, which is controlled by the keyboard
  rect (keyPaddleX, keyPaddleY, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);

  //the right paddle, which is controlled by the mouse
  rect (mousePaddleX, mousePaddleY, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
}

void drawScore() {

  textSize(20);

  String toPrint = "Keyboard: " + keyScore;

  text(toPrint, width/4-textWidth(toPrint)/2, 50);

  toPrint = "Mouse: "+ mouseScore;

  text(toPrint, width*3/4-textWidth(toPrint)/2, 50);
}

/*this funtion puts the ball back into the centre of the screen when it fails to hit either
 the paddle or the top or the bottom of the screen 
 */
void defaultBall () {

  if ((ballPositionX < -ballSize/2) || (ballPositionX > width + ballSize)) {

    ballPositionX = width/2;
    ballPositionY = height/2;
  }
}

void scoreCount () {

  if (ballPositionX  < -ballSize/2) {

    mouseScore = mouseScore + 1;
  }

  if (ballPositionX > width + ballSize) {

    keyScore =  keyScore + 1;
  }
}


void bounce () {
  //bouncing off the top and bottom of the screen  
  if (moveDown) {

    ballPositionY += MIN_SPEED +(sin(QUARTER_PI));
  } else {

    ballPositionY -= MIN_SPEED + (sin(QUARTER_PI));
  }

  if (moveRight) {

    ballPositionX += MIN_SPEED + (sin(HALF_PI + QUARTER_PI));

  } else {

    ballPositionX -= MIN_SPEED + (sin(-PI));
  }

  /*if (moveNewSpeed) {

   ballPositionX = ballPositionX + MAX_SPEED + (sin(QUARTER_PI));
   } else {

   ballPositionX = ballPositionX - MAX_SPEED + (cos(QUARTER_PI));
   }
  */
}

void paddleBounce () {


  if (ballPositionX <= (keyPaddleX + PADDLE_WIDTH + ballSize/2) && ballPositionY < (keyPaddleY + 100) && ballPositionY > (keyPaddleY) && ballPositionX > keyPaddleX  ) {

    moveRight = true;
    MIN_SPEED = 8;


  }


  if (ballPositionX >= (mousePaddleX - ballSize/2) && ballPositionY > (mousePaddleY) && ballPositionY < (mousePaddleY + 100) && ballPositionX < mousePaddleX ) {

    moveRight = false;
    MIN_SPEED = 8;


  }

  /*if (ballPositionX == keyPaddleX + PADDLE_WIDTH && ballPositionY == keyPaddleY + PADDLE_WIDTH ) {

   moveNewSpeed  = false;  

   } 

   if (ballPositionX == mousePaddleX && ballPositionY == mousePaddleY) {

   moveNewSpeed = true;

   }   

   */

}

void canvasBounce () {

  if (ballPositionY < ballSize/2) {

    moveDown = true;
  }

  if (ballPositionY > height - ballSize/2) {

    moveDown = false;
  }

}

void gameover () {

  if (gameOver) {

    ballSpeedX = 0;
    ballSpeedY = 0;
    paddleSpeed = 0;
    ballPositionX = width/2;
    ballPositionY = height/2;

    textSize(50);

    fill (random(255), random(255), random (255));

    String toPrint = "GAME OVER!!";

    text(toPrint, width/2-textWidth(toPrint)/2, height/2);
  }

  if (keyScore == 11 || mouseScore == 11) {

    gameOver = true;
  } else {

    gameOver = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code instead of just doing the OP's work for them.

Comment: @YOUSFIMohamedWalid The questioner asked: *"I want my ball to increase its speed when it **hits the edge** of a paddle and then return back to its normal speed when it **hits the middle** of the paddle"*